# sql query select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 have a database name "test.db" that contains two tables, login and manager

login table attributes

```
_id|username|password|manager_id
```

manager table attributes

```
manager_id|name|role
```

manager_id is a foreign key of login table. 
I inserted some values into the table

login

```
1|gmJohn|abc|1
2|gmJane|def|2
```

manager

```
1|john|GM
2|jane|Staff
```

I am trying to query the name,role of a manager against it's username and password

for example
    username:gmJohn,password:abc = name:john,role:GM

I tried this query

```
select name,role from login,manager where username="gmJohn" and password="abc";
```

But it's returns me this result.

```
john|GM
jane|Staff
```

expected results

```
john|GM
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct. You don't explain on which field you want a join.

Try something like this:

```
select name, role from manager m inner join login l on l.manager_id = m.manager_id where username="gmJohn" and password="abc";
```